# Tridion 2011 SP1 Database Manager error

Tags: tridion

When we try to add the MTSUser details in the Database Wizard we get the error:

> "Warning: The logon attempt of MTSUser on the local machine failed
>   with reason: Logon type not granted. If the values you have entered
>   are correct for the management system server choose OK otherwise
>   choose cancel to return to the previous dialog".

I'm pretty sure the account details are correct and I've stumbled across an old Tridion forum post from 2003 that states this was a known problem in certain circumstances where the type of logon the wizard attempts can fail. It was intended to try and give some immediate feedback e.g. if a password was wrong.

Is this still the case nine years later? I want to click continue but also want to avoid problems further down the line!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry it's not an error, but a warning. When installing the CMS it will add the right policies to the user, but as the db is created first, this has not been done YET. I know I know, confusing and partly my fault as I noticed it during the 5.0 product when I was still in charge of the installers, yet did not want to delay the release to change the message :) sorry!

To SDL R&D: please change the wording, ow and also the message when closing the TDM, I always think I close it while it's still doing something.

Comment: If you want R&D to change the wording, I'd suggest using the ideas site. In fact, this wording was very carefully thought out (I was there) and says exactly what it was intended to say.

Answer (score 3):

It was a design requirement of the Tridion Database Manager that it should be capable of running from a completely different machine than the Content Manager, and in principle from a machine with completely different security configuration.

When you enter the account details, it does "best effort" to help you avoid some obvious mistakes, but given the above, it's impossible for this to be more than a warning. What that text actually means is: "We fully understand that you might know more about your environment than this software is able to detect, so please interpret this warning based on your own knowledge."

When you provide your credentials, it attempts to log on "as a batch job". If it fails, then you get a warning.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen that error in a while, so there may be something wrong with it. The worst that can happen if you proceed is that

1. you may have to change some permission for the user or
2. change the user name in the TRUSTEES table later.

Logon type not granted suggests that the MTSUser account is not allowed to either login as a batch or login interactively (not sure which one the DB manager is trying to use), and it's easy to solve in any case.

If the installer gives you the same trouble, then it's more problematic. All the DB manager does with this info is to add the user to the TRUSTEES table.